# To stop finding running average once the condition fails?

Tags: python

Consider the code below:

```
 sub = [767220, 769287, 770167, 770276, 770791, 770835, 771926, 1196500, 1199789,      1201485, 1206331, 1206467, 1210929, 1213184, 1213204, 1213221, 1361867, 1361921, 1361949, 1364886, 1367224, 1368005, 1368456, 1368982, 1369000, 1370365, 1370434, 1370551, 1371492, 1471407, 1709408, 1710264, 1710308, 1710322, 1710350, 1710365, 1710375]
 avg = []; final = [] 

 def runningMean(seq, n=0, total=0): #function called recursively
       if not seq:
         return []
       total =total+int(seq[-1])
       return runningMean(seq[:-1], n=n+1, total=total) + [total/float(n+1)]

 def main():

    avg = runningMean(sub,n = 0,total = 0) #function call to obtain running mean starting from last element in the list i,e 1710375
    print avg
    for i in range(len(sub)):
      if (int(sub[i]) > float(avg[i] * 0.9)): #checking the condition
         final.append(sub[i])
    print final


 if __name__ == '__main__':
       main()
```

output consists of list of runningmean & the sub list doesn't satisfy the condition :

```
  [1282960.6216216215, 1297286.75, 1312372.4571428571, 1328319.6764705882, 1345230.0909090908, 1363181.3125, 1382289.2580645161, 1402634.7, 1409742.7931034483, 1417241.142857143, 1425232.111111111, 1433651.3846153845, 1442738.76, 1452397.5, 1462798.0869565217, 1474143.2727272727, 1486568.142857143, 1492803.2, 1499691.7368421052, 1507344.111111111, 1515724.0, 1525005.25, 1535471.9333333333, 1547401.642857143, 1561126.2307692308, 1577136.75, 1595934.1818181819, 1618484.2, 1646032.3333333333, 1680349.875, 1710198.857142857, 1710330.6666666667, 1710344.0, 1710353.0, 1710363.3333333333, 1710370.0, 1710375.0]

  [1361867, 1361921, 1361949, 1364886, 1367224, 1709408, 1710264, 1710308, 1710322, 1710350, 1710365, 1710375]
```

What I need to do is it should stop the finding of running average once the condition fails

```
(sub[i] > float(avg[i] * 0.9))
```

i,e the result should be:

```
  [1680349.875, 1710198.857142857, 1710330.6666666667, 1710344.0, 1710353.0, 1710363.3333333333, 1710370.0, 1710375.0]
  [1709408, 1710264, 1710308, 1710322, 1710350, 1710365, 1710375]
```

If anyone could suggest a solution in python for this it will be helpful.

Comment: Your algorithm for a running average isn't correct, I don't think. Basically, each result is the average of the current value and all the ones that follow it, equally weighted. Previous values are ignored. This isn't really an answer though, so I'm leaving it as a comment.

Comment: @Blckknght My running average algorithm works correctly i am finding the running average starting from the last item of the list for ex:1710375 the running avg is-1710375.0 next for (1710365+1710375)/2 ==1710370.0 & so on

Comment: OK, just wanted to make sure that was really what you wanted. It's not the first thing I'd expect when you just describe it as a "running average" though.

Comment: Rather than reversing the list using -1. It is simpler to reverse it at input level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reimplementing your average calculator as a generator. A generator only calculates as much as it needs to yield the next value as it is being iterated upon. If you stop iterating early, the rest of the calculations won't be done.

Furthermore, it's much easier to design your code to iterate forwards, rather than backwards. If you need to go backwards, use the `reversed` function to get a reverse iterator, or call the `reverse` method on a list.

Here's a generator that computes cumulative averages (in a forwards direction, not backwards):

```
def runningMean(iterable):
    """A generator, yielding a cumulative average of its input."""
    num = 0
    denom = 0
    for x in iterable:
        num += x
        denom += 1
        yield num / denom
```

To get the reverse cumulative average you want, you'll need to use this on a `reversed` iterator of your original data:

```
>>> sub = [767220, 769287, 770167, 770276, 770791, 770835, 771926, 1196500, 1199789,      1201485, 1206331, 1206467, 1210929, 1213184, 1213204, 1213221, 1361867, 1361921, 1361949, 1364886, 1367224, 1368005, 1368456, 1368982, 1369000, 1370365, 1370434, 1370551, 1371492, 1471407, 1709408, 1710264, 1710308, 1710322, 1710350, 1710365, 1710375]
>>> list(runningMean(reversed(sub)))
[1710375.0, 1710370.0, 1710363.3333333333, 1710353.0, 1710344.0, 1710330.6666666667, 1710198.857142857, 1680349.875, 1646032.3333333333, 1618484.2, 1595934.1818181819, 1577136.75, 1561126.2307692308, 1547401.642857143, 1535471.9333333333, 1525005.25, 1515724.0, 1507344.111111111, 1499691.7368421052, 1492803.2, 1486568.142857143, 1474143.2727272727, 1462798.0869565217, 1452397.5, 1442738.76, 1433651.3846153845, 1425232.111111111, 1417241.142857143, 1409742.7931034483, 1402634.7, 1382289.2580645161, 1363181.3125, 1345230.0909090908, 1328319.6764705882, 1312372.4571428571, 1297286.75, 1282960.6216216215]
```

You can reverse this with the `list.reverse()` method, if you want to see it in the same order as the original input, but if you wanted to stop the calculation early, I think you need to keep it going backwards for a little longer.

To stop when you find a value that's more than 10% greater than the cumulative average, you can use `itertools.takewhile`:

```
import itertools

results = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x[0] > 0.9 * x[1],
                                   itertools.izip(reversed(sub),
                                                  runningMean(reversed(sub)))))
```

In Python 3, use the regular `zip` builtin, rather than `itertools.izip`.

That gives you a list of the values and averages that met your condition, starting from the end and stopping just before the first value that failed the test. Here's how you can see them:

```
results.reverse() # put them back in regular order
for value, average in results:
    print value, results
```

Output:

```
1709408 1710198.857142857
1710264 1710330.6666666667
1710308 1710344.0
1710322 1710353.0
1710350 1710363.3333333333
1710365 1710370.0
1710375 1710375.0
```

Comment: @Blckknghtdef runningMean(iterable):
    
    num = 0
    denom = 0
    for x in iterable:
        num += x
        denom += 1
        yield num / denom


avg = list(runningMean(reversed(sub))):
   print avg          when i do this its not giving me the running average but just printing the sub list in reverse order

Comment: @JhonWatson: Hmm, I can't see how that would happen. Are you sure it's exactly the reverse of the original values, not just other integers? In Python 2, you may need to make sure you do `from __future__ import division` at the top of your file (before any other imports), or the division will truncate to the next smallest integer. Or, I suppose, another fix would be to initialize `num` or `denom` to `0.0` rather than just `0`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub = [767220, 769287, 770167, 770276, 770791, 770835, 771926, 1196500, 1199789,      1201485, 1206331, 1206467, 1210929, 1213184, 1213204, 1213221, 1361867, 1361921, 1361949, 1364886, 1367224, 1368005, 1368456, 1368982, 1369000, 1370365, 1370434, 1370551, 1371492, 1471407, 1709408, 1710264, 1710308, 1710322, 1710350, 1710365, 1710375]

def runningMean(seq, n=0, total=0): #function called recursively
    if not seq:
        return []
    total = total + int(seq[-1])
    if int(seq[-1]) < total/float(n+1) * 0.9:  # Check your condition to see if it's time to stop averaging.
        return []
    return runningMean(seq[:-1], n=n+1, total=total) + [total/float(n+1)]

avg = runningMean(sub, n = 0, total = 0)

print avg
print sub[-len(avg):]
```

Comment: if a want to print the seq also which satisfies the condition how to do it????i,e [1709408, 1710264, 1710308, 1710322, 1710350, 1710365, 1710375]

Comment: @JhonWatson Added it above.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the expected running average I ran:

```
sub.reverse()
avg = runningMean(sub,n = 0,total = 0) #function call to obtain running mean starting from last element in the list i,e 1710375
print avg
```

The next comparison section is not clear. Could you describe the algorithm in words.